# MySQL: Cursor for select from temp table

Tags: mysql, cursor

I need to `select column` from `temp` table in stored procedure for `cursor`.

Here is the following script of my attempt:

**Attempt**:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sptest2`(IN nm VARCHAR(50),IN sub VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

DECLARE dp char(50);
DECLARE colmn_list varchar(100);


SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tem AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT ', nm ,' AS Col FROM table1)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

DECLARE cursor_n CURSOR for select col from tem;
```

**Note**: This gives me error. Because we can't `declare cursor` after some operations. We need to declare it after the `BEGIN`.

So what is the solution for this?

Comment: I suggest you to do not use cursor. You can achieve same functionality by subqueries

Comment: @RonakShah, Sorry! But I am new to MySQL, Can you please elaborate?

Comment: No problem Meem, I think you want to use cursor to iterate row by row and do some processing right.. It will slow compare to you use subquery or joins

Comment: @RonakShah, Exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All declarations must be placed at begin of procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sptest2`(IN nm VARCHAR(50),IN sub VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

DECLARE dp char(50);
DECLARE colmn_list varchar(100);
DECLARE cursor_n CURSOR for select col from tem;


SET @q = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tem AS 
(SELECT DISTINCT ', nm ,' AS Col FROM table1)');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But depending on your requirements, is a better solution to use subqueries.

May be is a good idea drop table before try to create it because it function will be called more than one time.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tem;
```

Comment: But how can I store multiple rows into variable without using `cursor`? And how can I do it using subqueries?